# Charge state in Accelerator physics

Tags: nuclear-physics, notation, nuclear-engineering, particle-accelerators, ions

while asking for calculation of magnetic rigidity for accelerators, I am seeing notations like '**238-U-28+**' & '**197-Au-77+**

Previously I was comfortable seeing charge state like **40-Ca-1+** ions before. which would obviously mean Calcium ion with a positive charge or that has lost one electron. But here U-28+ it seems a little crazy to me.
if anyone can explain it would really helpful

Comment: What exactly is crazy about  28+ charge on a uranium atom? Fully stripped ions (no electrons at all left) are not uncommon, particularly for something like RHIC. No, such a charge state is not crazy.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_charged_ion for example.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.7974 as well. Gotten from googling "formation of highly charged ions accelerator"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A neutral uranium atom has 92 electrons to go with its 92 protons. With so many electrons around one nucleus, the outermost electrons are much more loosely bound to the nucleus because there are so many electrons  between them and the nucleus. The positive charge of the nucleus is screened by the inner electrons, so the outer electrons aren't as attracted. So, it is very easy to remove a lot of electrons from a uranium atom. This is also the reason that xenon can form compounds despite being a noble gas. The large number of electrons allow the outer most electrons to bind with other atoms like oxygen and fluorine.